# Geolocation cordova Android plugin does not work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps, ionic-framework

I am developing an application which 70% of it is based on geolocation. I began to develop in the iOS and everything works great, I had some problems but nothing that is not solvable logically. Now, I was asked a version for Android, at first impression, everything works identical to iOS, but when the testing version that give me problems arose geolocation. The problem is that being off the GPS from the phone (I tested Samsung, Xperia, Motorolas) fall into the error function (which I defined) to alert the user that the GPS was off and that should enable it to occupy. However, activating it, it does not work well, restart the computer to work correctly recently, I'm crazy, because even I get an error response, or alerts you leave, or anything like that.

My code :

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
 $(function(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 })

 function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
 }

 function onSuccess(pos) {
  $scope.latitud = pos.coords.latitude
  $scope.longitud =  pos.coords.longitude;
  console.log(pos.coords.latitude);
  $scope.mostrar_cercanos = true;
  $scope.getViews();
 }

 function onError(error) { 
  $scope.mostrar_cercanos = false;
  $scope.mostrar_mensaje_gps = true;
  $scope.mensaje = "El GPS de su telefono no se encuentra activado";
 }
})
```

Plugins :

```
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
```

I have to go back to iOS mention that everything works as I want.

Comment: That last part isn't clear to me "However, activating it, it does not work well, restart the computer to work correctly recently, I'm crazy, because even I get an error response, or alerts you leave, or anything like that."

Comment: BTW, cordova geolocation plugin for android uses HTML5 geolocation, so no native code involved, so it all deppends on the webview

Comment: @jcesarmobile What I mean is that active GPS Android device and does not work geolocation, the only way to make it work is Enable GPS, turn the device on again and work there again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use **ngcordova**.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

I have used this in my application and it worked fine.

Good luck!

Comment: This works for me, but I have some doubts. I have turned off the GPS on my phone, even so is my latitude and longitude? The plugins work with HTML5 and this is independent of the GPS cell? If so, to identify which show the user an error if it can not get your current position?